# Application always starts in background process after Windows 10 update

Tags: windows-10, firefox, process

I did last Tuesday Update on my Windows 10, after that my Firefox, which is not changed, starts ok but always in background process, so I can't access its GUI.

I have last stable version of Firefox and I did every apdate on Windows 10.

My Firefox is called by simple short with no arguments in its command line.

No other visible bad side effect is observeable.

I tried restart Windows and FF (in Task Manager) many times. I have no recent restore point to help. I reinstalled FF. I tried change resolution, start with compatibilitily mode in several combinations. No virus.

Renaming FF's default profile I got FF as a foreground process and it display an error about missing profile. I still trying to save this FF instalation and profile.

I am looking for some help before reinstall Windows.

Comment: I think you'd better check if there is a virus or malware infection

Comment: @spike_66 updated